# Unable to run compiled TypeScript code due to "Cannot find module" error

Tags: node.js, typescript

Here's my tsconfig.json configuration:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  }
}
```

I'm using relative imports in the code with the help of `baseUrl`.

The code compiles without any issues using `tsc -p .`, but when I try to run it with `NODE_PATH=./build node ./build/app.js`, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '<PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME>/app/listeners/module.ts'
Require stack:
{
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '<PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME>/bot/build/app/listeners.js',
    '<PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME>/bot/build/app.js'
  ]
}
```

In the listeners.js, a loop reads all the files under the `app/listeners` folder and calls the default exported function in the module.

I don't know if it's the expected behavior but looks like it searches the TypeScript module under `app` instead of looking for the JS version under `build/app`.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully run my compiled TypeScript code?

EDIT: Here's the directory structure:

```
.
├── app.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── app
    ├── registerListeners.ts
    ├── listeners
    │   └── actions
    │       └── edit.ts
    ├── views
    └── modals
```

Comment: Why you are using NODE_PATH=./build?

Comment: Without using it, even ts-node refuses to work with relative imports let alone running a compiled build.

Comment: could you please describe the directory structure of your project? where have you put your tsconfig.json file?